# SqlException in ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, database

Here is my code, whenever I input in the text boxes then click the button then an error occurs:

> SqlException was unhandled, Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Please help

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=XXYZZ\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\trist\Documents\Invent.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("Insert into tblLogin values ('"+ txtUsername.Text + '"'+ txtPassword.Text + "')",con);

    con.Open();
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    if (i > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Registered");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("HEHE");
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed a `,` in between two values that you are passing! beware of sql injection

Comment: You should really make use of [Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Answer (score 2):

Your insert SQL has two column values which must be separated with comma, but there is none:

```
// your incorrect SQL query:
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("Insert into tblLogin values ('"+ txtUsername.Text + '"'+ txtPassword.Text + "')",con);
```

But instead of fixing this you should start using parameterized queries, f.e. to prevent SQL injection:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("Insert into tblLogin values (@user, @password)",con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  txtUsername.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  txtPassword.Text;
```

You should also use the `using` statement for everything that implements `IDisposable` like the connection and the command. On that way you f.e. ensure that the connection gets disposed/closed(important) even in case of an exception.

Comment: And in addition, I'd recommend to *always* explicitly specify the columns of the table you're inserting your data into. Helps avoid unnecessary surprises and troubles

Answer (score -2):

You missed a comma (`,`) between

```
values ('"+ txtUsername.Text + '"'+ txtPassword.Text + "')",con);
```

better to specify the column names.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(Column1, Column2) 
VALUES (Value1, Value2), (Value1, Value2)
```